# Video editing software/Screen recording software with motion blur effect

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, desktop-recording

I'm linux gamer, and I want a screen recorder or video editing software that has motion blur effect. I want to render a video with smooth gameplay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For screen recording, I use Kazam which is a good application but I don't know others well.

[This link should help you choose](http://hackerspace.kinja.com/screen-recording-in-linux-1686055808)

For the editing software, there is Blender (if you go to the properties panel, in the export tab, there is the option for a motion blur)

Openshot is a easier video editor and it most probably has the motion blur effect. I also saw on another forum that Avidemux has this effect but I'm not sure.

Comment: Umm. I can't find motin blur effect in Openshot.

Comment: It seems that Openshot doesn't have the motion blur effet for now...